# AngularJS : Factory JSON Array with HTTP GET

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I'm developing my first AngularJS app using the Google Docs API to pass it JSON data.
This is an example of the factory I'm using:

```
app.factory('Data', ['$http', 'apiKeys', function($http, apiKeys){
  var googleDocs = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/';
  return {
    news:function () {
      return $http.get(googleDocs + apiKeys.googleDoc +'/1/public/values?alt=json', {cache: true});
    },
    updates:function () {
      return $http.get(googleDocs + apiKeys.googleDoc +'/2/public/values?alt=json', {cache: true});
    },
    docs:function () {
      return $http.get(googleDocs + apiKeys.googleDoc +'/3/public/values?alt=json', {cache: true});
    }
}]);
```

I wanted to clean up a bit the code and decided to use services instead of making the calls in the controller itself. It works normally, but it's a pain in the ass the fact that I still need to write long $scopes because of the structure of the Google API. This is how I get the values in the controller:

```
app.controller('homeCt', ['$scope', 'Data', function ($scope, Data){
  Data.news().success(function (data) {
    $scope.totalNews = data.feed.entry.length;
  });
}]);
```

Is there a way that I can set the factory service to pass me the data just using:

```
$scope.totalNews = Data.news()
```

Or at least removing the 'feed.entry'?

```
Data.news().success(function (data) {
  $scope.totalNews = data.length;
});
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example of service - resolve the success with the data you want

```
app.service('Data', ['$http', 'apiKeys', function($http, apiKeys){
  var googleDocs = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/';

 this.news =function(){

    return $http.get(googleDocs + apiKeys.googleDoc +'/1/public/values? alt=json', {cache: true})
    .then(function(data){

      return data.feed.entry.length;

   });
   }

}]);
```

the controller - since you already resolved the data in service hence..

```
app.controller('homeCt', ['$scope', 'Data', function ($scope, Data){
  Data.news().then(function (data) {
    $scope.totalNews = data;
   });
}]);
```

working example

```
  var app = angular.module('app', ['ionic'])
 .service('Data', ['$http',
function($http) {
     var googleDocs =       'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1aC1lUSxKatfxMKEy1erKDSAKgijSWOh77FDvKWhpwfg/1/public/values?alt=json';
  this.news = function() {
    return $http.get(googleDocs, {
      cache: true
    }).then(function(res) {

      return res.data.feed.entry;
    });
  }
}
 ])
  .controller('homeCt', ['$scope', 'Data',
    function($scope, Data) {
  Data.news().then(function(data) {

    console.log(data);
  })
}
 ]);
```

Comment: Thanks Pranay, I already tried that before but it gives me an 'undefined' erorr. `TypeError: undefined is not a function at new <anonymous> (app.js:154)`

Comment: are your sure because i use this technique many times in my project's

Comment: I tried your example and finally got it to work using that! Thank you very much for your help Pranay!!

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a way of doing it, a way that I don't recommend at all (a service should not handle the scope), but for me it is the only way you have if you don't want to destroy the "async" of your ajax call :

```
app.factory('Data', ['$http', 'apiKeys', function($http, apiKeys){
  var googleDocs = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/';
  return {
    news:news,
    updates: updates,
    [...]
  }

function news(scopeValue) {
  $http.get(googleDocs + apiKeys.googleDoc +'/1/public/values?alt=json', {cache: true}).success(function(data){
    scopeValue = data;
 });

}]);
```

and then, call it that way in your controller :

```
 Data.news($scope.totalNews);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Jean-Philippe, I tried using your's but I couldn't get it to work following your instructions. I solved this issue using Pranay's suggestion. Thank you again for taking your time to help me, I'm very grateful!

Comment: maybe my syntax had errors (I did it directly here), what error did you have? You will lose a lot of performance and your interfaces will be very slow if you handle your queries that way